# Animate movement with hover jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I'm trying to get an image-link to bob up and back down on hover with jquery...but so far nothing's worked. Heres the code:

```
$("#footer").find("a").hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        down: '+=10'
    }, 200);
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({
        down: '-=10'
    }, 200);
});
```

Comment: don't you mean: top: '+=10'?

Comment: down is not a property, use top or bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS property you're looking for is `bottom`, not `down`.

```
$("#footer").find("a").hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        bottom: '+=10'
    }, 200);
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({
        bottom: '-=10'
    }, 200);
});
```

Also check that in your CSS, the positioning for mage-links is relative or absolute and that you have set some value for bottom. Otherwise it won't work.

```
a {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
}​
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NBqTu/) where I've set up the above code.

Comment: Thanks! Really helped, but is it possible for the images to stop bobbing up and down once the mouse leaves the area?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for it to bob up and down once when the user's mouse enters the link try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PT8St/1/)

```
$(".animate_handler").mouseover(function () {
    $(".animate_link").animate({top: '-=10px'}, 200).animate({top: '+=10px'}, 200);
});
```

Notice that the link is inside a container with enough room at the bottom of the link to prevent the animation from recurring when the link animates out of the scope of the mouse.